# Несколько вопросов по С/С++

Tags: c++, c

Несколько вопросов:

**1)** Первый вопрос в следующем, правильно ли говорить, что подключается библиотека или правильно будет подключается заголовочный файл в языках C\C++?
Простой пример:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) { ... }

#include <iostream>
int main() { ... }
```

Я думаю, что при подключении библиотеки при помощи ***pragma*** все равно нужно тащить ее заголовочный файл, но это именно заголовочный файл, а не библиотека.

**2)** Второй вопрос в следующем, при написании кода на С++, стоит ли отказаться от использования макроподстановок в пользу типизированных констант?
Например, вместо

```
#define N 5
```

написать

```
const int N = 5
```

И откзааться от макросов-функций в пользу **inline** функций?

**3)** Третий вопрос, почему некоторые товарищи считают, что в языке СИ нельзя использовать переменные - итераторы непосредственно в заголовке цикла? Возможно, это действительно запрещалось в каком либо старом стандарте, но я с такой проблемой лично не сталкивался.

Comment: Рекомендую разделить этот вопрос на три отдельных, т. к. они решительно ничем не связаны.

Comment: @D-side они все заданы одним и тем же участником, например :)

Comment: Будь каждый вопрос оформлен отдельно - я бы плюсанул все из них. А так - не могу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> правильно ли говорить, что подключается библиотека или правильно будет подключается заголовочный файл в языках C\C++?

В классическом случае заголовочный файл и сама библиотека - две отдельные сущности.

- В классическом случае включение заголовочного файла не является подключением библиотеки. Заголовочный файл - это лишь "анонс" содержимого библиотеки, а не сама библиотека. Сама библиотека подключается отдельно, каким-то платформенно-зависимыми средствами.

  В вашем примере фигурируют заголовочные файлы *стандартной* библиотеки. Сама стандартная библиотека как правило подключается компилятором автоматически, поэтому у новичков часто возникает иллюзия того, что библиотеки подключаются просто включением заголовочного файла.
- В связи с популярностью шаблонного программирования в С++ последнее время натуральным образом появились библиотеки, состоящие *только* из заголовочных файлов (чисто заголовочная библиотека, header-only library). В таком случае включение заголовочного фала фактически и является включением всей библиотеки прямо в ваш код. Больше просто нечего подключать. Это еще одна причина того, почему включение заголовочного фала иногда называют "подключением библиотеки" (в данном случае - справедливо называют).

  Например, та часть стандартной библиотеки С++, которая исторически называется STL, обычно реализуется как чисто заголовочная библиотека.
- На платформе MSVC существует практика создания заголовочных файлов библиотек, которые внутри себя уже содержат директиву `#pragma`, которая также обеспечивает и подключение самой библиотеки к проекту. Таким образом, выполняя включение заголовочного файла вы автоматически вызываете и подключение соответствующей библиотеки. В таком случае тоже можно говорить, что включив такой заголовочный файл вы тем самым подключили и саму библиотеку... но все таки стоит понимать суть процесса.

  Возможность подключения библиотек через директиву в исходнике (`#pragma`) - очень грамотное и полезное свойство MSVC, но оно свойственно только MSVC.

> при подключении библиотеки при помощи pragma все равно нужно тащить ее заголовочный файл

Разумеется. Заголовочный файл всегда нужен, независимо от того, надо ли вам что-то подключать при помощи `#pragma`. Но еще раз: подключение библиотек через `#pragma` - свойство только MSVC. На других платформах библиотеки подключают не через `#pragma`, и аналогов такой функциональности пока не видно.

> при написании кода на С++, стоит ли отказаться от использования макроподстановок в пользу типизированных констант

Да, за исключением тех ситуаций, когда имеет место смешанный С/С++ проект. В заголовочных файлах, которые потенциально могут включаться и в С код, следует придерживаться `#define`.

Также, когда речь идет о константах времени компиляции, можно посоветовать использовать `constexpr` вместо `const`.

> и откзааться от макросов-функций в пользу inline функций?

Там, где это возможно/оправданно - да.

Судя по вашему третьему вопросу (как я его понял), вы пользуетесь более-менее современными компиляторами С, поддерживающим стандарт С99 или выше. Тогда в вашем С уже есть inline-функции и там, где это возможно, стоит использовать именно их даже в С коде.

Однако стоит заметить, что типонезависимые (type-agnostic) макросы в С являются скорее заменителями *шаблонных* инлайновых функций в С++. Поэтому переход от макросов к обычным inline-функциям не всегда возможен/оправдан.

> Третий вопрос, почему некоторые товарищи считают, что в языке СИ нельзя использовать переменные - итераторы непосредственно в заголовке цикла?

Если речь идет об *объявлении* переменных в заголовке цикла, то это свойство стандарта С99 и старше. В до-С99 языке это не разрешалось.

Comment: Простите, но можно ли с вами связаться по почте?)

Answer (score 4):

1. Библиотека подключается, заголовочный файл включается... :)
2. Да.
3. Было нельзя, в современном стандарте - вполне.
4. Краткость - с.т. :)

Answer (score 1):

Небольшая ремарка по поводу пункта 3, но немножко в другом ракурсе: почему в языке C++ не просто можно, а *рекомендуется* объявлять переменные непосредственно перед местом их использования. В том числе и в циклах.

Например, потому, что подобная запись:

```
Foo bar;
```

в C++ тянет за собой конструктор `Foo`. А он, в свою очередь, может оказаться не таким уж и лёгким, обладать побочными эффектами, и т.д. Но зачем нам всё это если, например, в ветке кода, по которой может пойти исполнение, эта переменная не будет использоваться вообще?

Comment: Ну в то же время не стоит забывать, что объявление переменной с тяжелой конструкцией/деструкцией в теле цикла может привести к ее конструкции/деструкции на каждой итерации. Иногда стоит и пожертвовать локальностью объявления (вынести объявление за цикл) во избежание таких ненужных расходов.